# Python - Why isn't my data being added correctly by this loop in sqlite3?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have been meaning to create one database with multiple tables using sqlite3, with each table containing a different set of data but all containing the same column labels and same number of rows.

I have this code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('qlsitheta16.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table(n):
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS qlttable_%s(oxygen INTEGER, distance REAL, q REAL, lsi REAL, \
theta TEXT)'%n)

def data_entry(n,oxy,dist,q_val,lsi_val,t_val):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO qlttable_%s VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"%n,[oxy,dist,q_val,lsi_val,t_val])

def del_and_update(n,min_dist,oxy):
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM qlttable_%s'%n)
    c.execute("UPDATE qlttable_%s SET distance = ? WHERE oxygen= ?"%n,[min_dist,oxy])

def del_and_update_q(n,q,oxy):
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM qlttable_%s'%n)
    c.execute("UPDATE qlttable_%s SET q = ? WHERE oxygen= ?"%n,[q,oxy])

def del_and_update_lsi(n,lsi,oxy):
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM qlttable_%s'%n)
    c.execute("UPDATE qlttable_%s SET lsi = ? WHERE oxygen= ?"%n,[lsi,oxy])

with open(inputfile, 'rb') as f:
    for frame in range(fr+1):
        create_table(frame)
        #...bunch of stuff...
        for n in range(len(solvent)):
            data_entry(frame,n,0,0,0,0)
            distances = []
                for i in range(len(refpts)):
                    do stuff to fill up distances
            del_and_update(frame,min(distances),n)

        for n in water_index:
        #do stuff
            if len(set_temp)>2:
                    del_and_update_q(frame,function1(set_temp),n)
        for n in water_index:
        #do stuff
            if len(set_temp)>2:
                    del_and_update_lsi(frame,function2(set_temp),n)

        conn.commit()
```

My entire code is 355 lines long, so I left out a lot of info.

For each frame, there should be a separate table (DONE), and each frame should have different values of the "distance" column, but instead I get the same values for all tables. I cannot understand why because I put an indicator of frame number for each data entry and update function.

EDIT: Everything works fine. I just didn't see the drop down menu for viewing each table separately. I feel dumb

Comment: use logging in each of function and then see if those are excecuted perfectly and you will see point they r breaking ,

Comment: also your 2nd loop re-uses the last frame from previous loop unless they were meant to be nested but they dont appear as such right now

Comment: @NikosM. I edited some blocks of code, hope you understand